# beautifulsoup get an element without using select

Tags: beautifulsoup

If i want to check if h2 with class d exists with in these three divs, how can i do this without using select ?

Basically I want to get text "test" if it only when exists under three divs by id and class.

```
<div id="a">
   <div class="b">
     <div id="c">
       <h2 class="d">
        test
       </h2>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>

<h2 class="d">don't get this</h2>
```

Thanks in advance for your help